# PHP regexp - find all URLs except special folders in URI

Tags: php, regex, url

Need to get all URLs like:

```
http://domain.name/novostroyki/novyy_petergof/

http://domain.name/novostroyki/novyy_petergof/?var1=value1&val2=value2=...
```

but not the following ones:

```
http://domain.name/novostroyki/novyy_petergof/flats/

http://domain.name/novostroyki/novyy_petergof/flats/?var1=value1&val2=value2=...
```

Tried something like that, but it doesn't work as I wish:

```
/novostroyki/((?!flats)[a-z_0-9A-Z\.])*/?\??(.*)/
```

Comment: find all urls with regular regex and then filter them?

Comment: actually i'm using Bitrix CMS, so i use this expression as a condition of linking specific templates to specific pages. It must be a holistic - because in other case i need to write hacks for admin-panel - this was in not elegant and is not welcomed at all.

![Bitrix Admin Panel](http://clip2net.com/clip/m59143/1338293509-clip-87kb.jpg)

Comment: Where are you trying to find these links? In a bunch of HTML (DOM parser) or in a block of natural language text (regex, albeit horrible) or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/novostroyki/((?!flats)[\w.]*/?)*(\?.*)?
```

Not sure if it will be fine in all cases - it certainly should be in the ones listed above.

Answer (score 0):

check if this suggestion is true:

> if an url matches the regex on the list, it doesn't continue to the next item on the list.

then you can use:

> the regex with all novostroyki after the regex with all novostroyki/flats/

Comment: tpaksu, i need 1 regexp, because AS I WROTE ABOVE, i type this in admin-panel, it should work "as is", without following filterings.